# How to change the host to use GeoLite2

Tags: python-3.x, api

hello i am new to coding and i wanted to build something for a personal project and i came across MaxMind's ip finding api. Their paid version which is GeoIp2 is a bit expensive for me but they do have a free version which is GeoLite2. But their documentation dont have any example to how to import it.

Python documentation for GeoIp2

```py
>>> import geoip2.webservice
>>>
>>> # This creates a Client object that can be reused across requests.
>>> # Replace "42" with your account ID and "license_key" with your license
>>> # key. Set the "host" keyword argument to "geolite.info" to use the
>>> # GeoLite2 web service instead of GeoIP2 Precision.
>>> with geoip2.webservice.Client(42, 'license_key') as client:
>>>
>>>     # Replace "city" with the method corresponding to the web service
>>>     # that you are using, i.e., "country", "city", or "insights". Please
>>>     # note that Insights is not supported by the GeoLite2 web service.
>>>     response = client.city('203.0.113.0')
```

In the comments they have mentioned to change the host to use GeoLite2 but i dont understand what i need to change. I tried every possible thing from my side and failed. If anyone can help me with this ;-;

Comment: An added keyword argument would look like this: `[...] webservice.Client(42, 'license_key', host='geolite.info') as [...]`. Unfortunately this does not lead to success, but results in an AuthenticationError. An obvious thought is that the comment might be out of date because the underlying API changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you leave out the 'host =' it works.
so just .Client(ID, License_key, "geolite.info")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).